# Spark save bytes as audio file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a bunch of sequence files where the keys are strings and the values themselves are the bytes that make up an entire audio file.

I'm able to load these sequence files successfully in Spark:

```
     val data = sc.sequenceFile(inputPath, classOf[Text], classOf[BytesWritable]).map{case (key, value) => value.copyBytes}
```

I want to store these values individually on HDFS, as audio files, but I cannot figure out how to do this. I've tried both saveAsPickleFile and saveAsObjectFile, but both serialize the data. What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage the following option,

**saveAsHadoopFile**(*path, outputFormatClass, keyClass=None, valueClass=None, keyConverter=None, valueConverter=None, conf=None, compressionCodecClass=None*)

Output a Python RDD of key-value pairs (of form RDD[(K, V)]) to any Hadoop file system, using the old Hadoop OutputFormat API (mapred package). Key and value types will be inferred if not specified. Keys and values are converted for output using either user specified converters or **org.apache.spark.api.python.JavaToWritableConverter**. The **conf** is applied on top of the base Hadoop conf associated with the SparkContext of this RDD to create a merged Hadoop MapReduce job configuration for saving the data.

Parameters:

- **path** – path to Hadoop file
- **outputFormatClass** – fully qualified classname of Hadoop OutputFormat
  (e.g. “org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat”)
- **keyClass** – fully qualified classname of key Writable class (e.g.
  “org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable”, None by default)
- **valueClass** – fully qualified classname of value Writable class (e.g.
  “org.apache.hadoop.io.Text”, None by default)
- **keyConverter** – (None by default) valueConverter – (None by default)
- **conf** – (None by default)
- **compressionCodecClass** – (None by default)

Hope, this helps.